# Parsing nested json returns null in object

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have the following json.

```
{
    "room1": {
        "first": "id1",
        "second": "id2",
        "third": "id3"
    },
    "room2": {
        "first": "id1",
        "second": "id2",
        "third": "id3"
    }
}
```

That I'm trying to deserialise with these two classes.

```
public class Streams
    {
        [JsonProperty("first")]
        public string first { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("second")]
        public string second { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("third")]
        public string third { get; set; }
    }

    public class Room
    {
            public string room { get; set; }
            public Streams streams { get; set; }
    }
```

My current code is simple:

```
Rooms r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rooms>(jsonstring);
```

I know my json string has more than one room, but if I add List it throws an exception. This line above goes through, however I get a null for room and streams.

I also tried to structure the Rooms class as

```
Dictionary<string, Streams> d { get; set; }
```

This didn't throw an exception, but still returned null.

EDIT:

I changed the json to look like this, and it's parsing well now.

```
[
{
    "room":"room1",
    "first": "id1",
    "second": "id2",
    "third": "id3"
},
{
    "room":"room1",
    "first": "id1",
    "second": "id2",
    "third": "id3"
}
```

]

Comment: Are you able to change your json at all?  `{"name":"room1", "streams": {"first"...} }` would be far easier to parse etc.  Working with properties whose names (rather than values) change is always awkward, if you're able to change your data structure at this stage of development it'll probably make things easier in the long run.

Comment: Try `.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, Streams>>(jsonstring);`

Comment: If your (json) object can contain an arbitrary number `n`  of rooms, than you are shooting yourself on the foot by defining `n` different fields in that object. You should simply contain them in a list and deserialize it accordingly. If thats not the case, then define a c# class with the respective field names and deserialize it accordingly.

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yes, I'm able to change the json. Can you let me know how to change the classes for the example json you provided?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo it's n arbitrary rooms, but I can change the json.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Rooms
{
        public Streams room1{ get; set; }
        public Streams room2{ get; set; }
}
Rooms r = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rooms>(jsonstring);
```

Comment: Please consider to include description for the applied solution for the OP's problem.

Answer (score 0):

your classes is wrong for this object

```
public class JsonClass
{
    public RoomClass room1 {get; set;}
    public RoomClass room2 {get; set;}
}

public class RoomClass
{
    [JsonProperty("first")]
    public string first { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("second")]
    public string second { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("third")]
    public string third { get; set; }
}
```

then

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonClass>(jsonstring);
```

**Edit: OP stated that there will be many rooms**

```
var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, RoomClass>>(jsonstring);
```

Comment: But this is just an example json. room1 and room2 are going to be MANY more rooms. Maybe the JsonClass can have public List<RoomClass>? I also need to be able to remember the key in a string.

Comment: So what's inside JsonClass? Is it still the individual room1 and room2? I'm trying to avoid that, ideally.

Comment: you dont need to use JSonClass